# Fuzzy owa operator

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I am reading about the allocation of OWA weigts from the article [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220063917_An_overview_of_methods_for_determining_OWA_weights)

In it one way of finding weights is through

[image]

Here with varying values for a,b they have shown this. Three situations are where (a,b)= (0.3,0.8),(0,0.5),(0.5,1)
[image]

But what does this mean? Say if the fuzzy rule is

> IF a and b and c then d

Then does "at least half" means when at least half of the a,b,c conditions are satisfied then d happens.
Is it something like that. Can someone please explain the effect from a,b?